# Google Site Search API - Filtering using multiple attributes

Tags: filter, google-search-api, google-custom-search

Is it possible to filter Google custom search results using multiple pagemap attributes?

For example, I want to filter results using meta tags `category_name` and `site_section`. I have tried to do this in different ways including the following, but it doesn't work:

```
?q=search_term+more:p:metatags-category_name:filter_term,more:p:metatags-site_section:filter_term
```

I have looked at the [Google developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#filter_by_attribute) but it only shows filtering using one attribute with multiple keywords.